# Session Attributes no longer work?

Tags: java, servlets

I am currently making a website, in which you can build a muffin. The muffin consists of Topping, and Bottom. It goes through 2 tables, with the name and price of the bottom and top. This is the function I use, to write each item, whether topping or bottom:

```
public String writeTopping(){
        String output = ""; 
        String topping;

        double price;
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://", "asdasd", "asdasdas");
            java.sql.Statement mySt = myConn.createStatement();
            String rs = "SELECT * FROM topping";
            ResultSet myRS = mySt.executeQuery(rs);
            while (myRS.next()) {
                topping = myRS.getString("topping");
                price = myRS.getDouble("price");
                topping tempTop = new topping(topping, price);
                 toppingCake.add(tempTop);
                 output += "<form method ='POST' action='Topping'><div class='panel panel-primary'><div class='panel-heading'>" + topping + "</div><div class='panel-body'><img src='http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE' class='img-responsive' style='width:100%' alt='Image'></div><div class='panel-footer'>Price: "+ price +"</div><button type='submit'>Add To Basket</button><input type='hidden' name='topping' value='"+topping+"'></div>";

            }

            myConn.close();
        } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        items.add(output);
        return output;



    }
```

Upon clicking on submit, on either of the items, the servlet sets the attribute for which topping you selected:

```
String toppingPage = request.getParameter("topping");

        switch (toppingPage) {
            case "Chocolate":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Blueberry":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Rasberry":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Crispy":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Strawberry":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Raisin":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Orange":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Lemon":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
            case "Blue Cheese":
                request.setAttribute("topping", toppingPage);
                response.sendRedirect("secondPage.jsp");
                break;
        }
```

And once at the final page, I would display the results with

```
<% out.print(session.getAttribute("topping")); %>
```

I had this working earlier today, however, I changed something, and now it keeps returning null for some reason.

Comment: Consider: `topping tempTop = new topping(topping, price);` is topping an object?

Comment: @YoungMillie Yes. It was used before to get the prices out at the final page, where I would loop through an arrayList, filled with topping / bottom objects, in order to find the prices... Been stuck at getting the name of the topping the customer chose for 2 hours because of this little error I made. Sorry of the confusion.

Comment: 1. All servlet environments are headless, so your JOptionPane will never display.  I suspect an exception is occurring which you cannot see.  2. You are not closing your `<form>` elements.  3.  Your `switch` statement does exactly the same thing for every topping;  if that is what you intended, you might as well replace it with the two lines of code from a `case` statement.

Comment: @VGR Tried to redo all the servlets, cases, and HTML... somehow still doesn't work. I don't know where it's going wrong. When reviewing the HTML, all the values are set correctly, and the output are as they should be. But when I try to request.setAttribute("topping",topSelected);, and then session.getAttribute("topping"),all it displays is null...

Comment: Request attributes and session attributes are disparate data.  Setting a request attribute does not make that attribute available in the session.  Try `request.getSession().setAttribute` instead.

Comment: @VGR Brother... I am so stupid. Terribly sorry for going through all this trouble. It worked with request.getSession().setAttribute. Thank you for your help